# Flutter | Firebase | Unable to print the message data with print(message.data)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am pursuing a course on Udemy on flutter development, I am a beginner trying to master flutter, In the mid-way of the course, my instructor has the below code:

```
  void getMessages() async {
    final messages = await _fireStore.collection('messages').get();
    for (var message in messages.docs) {
      print(message.data);
    }
  }
```

And I had the same code as above when executed, she was able to read the data of the messages in firestore, while I was unable to print the same message, even though the code was same, after tweaking the code, I changed my code as below, by just adding the '()' on the message.data();, Now I am also able to see the messages.

The question here is how did she get the data printed without using () on messages.data, I am a beginner, I would like to understand the logic, please.

```
  void getMessages() async {
    final messages = await _fireStore.collection('messages').get();
    for (var message in messages.docs) {
      print(message.data());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because, with the upgrade to [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/), they changed some method declarations & getters in the Firebase libraries.

`.data` to `data()`, `documents` to `docs` , etc...

Take a look at [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/), it might help you. It has all the documentation needed use Firebase with Flutter.

Comment: Thank-You for quick response, it was helpful and fueled my knowledge, I was beating my head. I thought I was missing something in my code.